# Get all Countries Name from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want list of countries name from DBpedia.

I am using http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ to execute my query, but till now I have not found all countries name which are available in DBpedia.

For Example : dbr:[United_Kingdom](http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States), dbr:[India](http://dbpedia.org/page/India), dbr:[United_States](http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States), etc.

Comment: OK, show us the SPARQL you have written so far, even if it doesn't get "all countries".

Comment: My SPARQL Query is `SELECT DISTINCT ?country WHERE {
 ?city rdf:type dbo:City ; 
       rdfs:label ?label ; 
       dbo:country ?country 
}
order by ?country`  or you can open this [link](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fcountry+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+%3Fcity+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3ACity+%3B+%0D%0A+++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+%3B+%0D%0A+++++++dbo%3Acountry+%3Fcountry+%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder+by+%3Fcountry)

Comment: you're not asking for all countries.  you are asking for all cities that have a  known relationships with a country.  this may sound academic, but maybe there are some countries in DBpedia for which there are no recorded cities.  Did you try the query I provided below?  it might be interesting to do a query using some of the classes I pointed to, and then `minus` out the countries that are available form your city-based question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the problem

1. You don't know how to write SPARQL in general?  (That's OK, it's hard to get started.)
2. You don' know about the classes and predicates in DBpedia?  (That's OK too.  I have to check each time.)
3. Something else?

This gets all UN member nations.  Getting "all countries"  is probably just a matter of finding the right class in their ontology.

```
select distinct ?s
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> }
```

I happen to know that New York City is the largest city in the United States, and that DBpedia has a `largestCity` predicate and a `New_York_City` instance. So I wrote a query that should only get the United States as the subject, and then asked for all connected predicates and objects.  You should look in that for an object that meets your exceptions for defining "all countries."  If you don't find one, you may have to `union` a few other triple patterns into one query.

I have also filtered out objects that contain either of two terms that be relevant for you:  "country" or "nation"

```
select distinct *
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> ;
dbo:largestCity  dbr:New_York_City ;
?p ?o
filter(isURI(?o))
filter((regex(lcase(str(?o)), "country")) || (regex(lcase(str(?o)), "nation")))

}
```

Gives the foloowing, which should help you write a followup question that isn't specific to the United States.

```
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     s                      |                        p                          |                                      o                                       |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink  | http://www.ifs.du.edu/ifs/frm_CountryProfile.aspx?Country=US                 |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink  | http://nationalatlas.gov/                                                    |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type   | http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Country108544813                               |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject                  | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:G7_nations                              |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type   | http://schema.org/Country                                                    |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#seeAlso      | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anti-miscegenation_laws                          |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject                  | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations     |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs              | http://transparency.270a.info/classification/country/US                      |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type   | http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country                                          |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type   | http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations          |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject                  | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:G8_nations                              |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs              | http://linked-web-apis.fit.cvut.cz/resource/united_states_of_america_country |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink  | http://www.nationalcenter.org/HistoricalDocuments.html                       |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink  | http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/country_profiles/1217752.stm             |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type   | http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Country                                            |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States  | http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject                  | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:G20_nations                             |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```